# the perl script is deleting only the contents inside the directory and not the directory

Tags: perl

I have the perl code to delete the files inside the directory and later the directory.

```
find ( sub {
  my $file = $File::Find::name;
  if ( -f $file ) {
    push (@file_list, $file);
  }
}, @find_dirs);

for my $file (@file_list) {
  my @stats = stat($file);
  if ($now-$stats[9] > $AGE) {
    unlink $file;
  }
}
```

But the above code is deleting only the contents inside the directories and sub directories leaving behind all the empty folder.
Could anyone please help me with the changes to be done to above coding so that it deletes the files and also the directories.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation in your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Sensible indentation is a useful way to make your code easier to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`unlink`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) does not delete directories, only files.

> Note: unlink will not attempt to delete directories unless you are
>   superuser and the -U flag is supplied to Perl. Even if these
>   conditions are met, be warned that unlinking a directory can inflict
>   damage on your filesystem. Finally, using unlink on directories is not
>   supported on many operating systems. Use rmdir instead.

You want [`rmdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rmdir.html), and you probably want to check with [`-d`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) which one to use, unless you don't care about warnings.

Comment: I think you mean "does not delete directories".

Comment: thanks...if i replace unlink by rmdir in the above code ...will it work perfectly?

Comment: @satvik No, because `rmdir` _only_ works on directories.

Comment: @tadman oops. Next time please go ahead and edit that kind of obvious faux pas out yourself. :)

Comment: @simbabque  i need to delete both the files and directories not only files..but present code is only deleting the files inside the directory and not the directory.

Comment: Re "*`unlink` does not delete directories*", Tha's only half of it. The other issue is that the directory is encountered before the files within.

Answer (score 1):

I am only putting the code together, so you may upvote @simbabque that answered first. Try:

```
finddepth( sub {
  my $file = $File::Find::name;
  my @stats = stat($file);
  if( -f $file && $now - $stats[9] > $AGE ) {
    unlink $file;
  }
  elsif( -d $file ) {
    rmdir $file;
  }
}, @find_dirs );
```

A few comments:

- `File::Find` will find both files and directories.
- `-f` checks for a file; `-d` for a directory.
- `rmdir` will only remove a directory if the directory is empty. That is why files must be deleted first. `finddepth` takes care of this.
- `-f` and `-d` are simple to use, but [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) may also be used for such a check (see second field, *mode*.)
- I have not tested the code; I cannot easily recreate your conditions.

**EDIT**: Now it uses `finddepth` instead of `find` because:

> finddepth() works just like find() except that it invokes the &wanted function for a directory after invoking it for the directory's contents. It does a postorder traversal instead of a preorder traversal, working from the bottom of the directory tree up where find() works from the top of the tree down.

This should take care of removing the directories in order, deepest first. Some directories may still not be removed if files remain in them that do not match the delete condition. If you want them removed when empty regardless of their timestamp, then remove the `if -d` condition. The non-empty ones will remain. Directories that cannot be removed may issue a warning...

Comment: thanks for the code...but this is not deleting all the directories ...the directories which contains sub directories are not being deleted but just it is getting emptied.

Comment: I see, that's what happens when code cannot be tested. This is so because a directory has to be empty in order to be deleted, so the order in which they are deleted matters. They have to be deleted in DFS order (the deepest first.) Can you adjust the code with this in mind or do you need more help?

Comment: @satvik, given your comment I have changed `find` to be `finddepth`. This should work for directory removal. See the added explanation.

Comment: thanks again...but this didnt help...i tried the new code but it is not deleted the directories

Comment: @satvik, the criterion to delete a directory is not clear to me. I have changed the code so that the deletion is attempted no matter what. Now they will be deleted as soon as they become empty. This seems to be what you need.